# how to get the same size like navigation bar using custom view?

Tags: ios, uiview

I need to recreate navigation bar using custom view, since it will be easier to make than inserting view to the actual navigation bar from apple.
I need to insert search bar and some buttons.

but I have problem to set the size of that custom navigation bar view, in some iOS device it seems little bit bigger than the navigation bar from apple, I set the autolayout like the picture below. constraint to leading, trailing and top to the superview and then set the aspect ration to 375:80

the custom view is the red one. the navigation bar in orangeVC is from apple using navigation controller

[image]

and here is the result, for iPhone XR, XSMax, it seems great, the size seems the same.

[image]

but for iPhone 8 it seems the custom view is slightly bigger
[image]

how to properly make custom view that has the same size like navigation bar from apple?

Comment: if you need IBDesignable file for this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52814651/why-the-autolayout-is-not-updated-if-i-use-ibdesignable-file-when-i-run-the-app/52868890#52868890

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where the ratio 375:80 are you getting from?
It's not correctly.
NavigationBar's height is 44 by default, and StatusBar is 44 for Notch type devices like iPhone X, XR, XS, XS Max and 20 in otherwise.

So you need to set 88 for Notch type devices and 64 for otherwise instead of ratio. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing needs to be calculated.

Navbar height should be 44.0 all the time.
But, Navbar top constraint should use **Safe Area** in place of superview. and add a status bar background view just to match your header color

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I found so far, without having to create a navigation controller instance:

```
[self.navigationBar sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero].height;
```